# What is the difference between server side rendering (Next.js) and Static Site rendering (Gatsby.js)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm looking to create a website that does not rely on client-side JavaScript, however, I still want to use SPA features like client-side routing etc, so I am looking at using a framework that does not render on the client-side. These 2 seem to be the top options for this type of thing, however, I'm unsure as to the differences between the 2 different types of server processing.

Comment: Client-side routing relies on JavaScript, so if you use Gatsby or Next and JS isn't available on the browser the site will just route normally with a refresh/navigation to a new page, you won't get the fast SPA client-side routing experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server side rendering is where a request is made from the client/browser to the server, and then at that point the HTML is generated on-the-fly **run-time** and sent back to the browser to be rendered.

Static site rendering is very similar, however the parsing is carried out during the **build time** instead. Therefore when a request is made the HTML is stored statically and can be sent straight back to the client.

---

They both have their pros and cons:

Although static sites will be faster at run-time as no server-side processing is required, it does mean that any changes to data require a full rebuild over the application server side.

Alternatively, with the server side approach, putting any caching aside, the data is processed on-the-fly and sent straight to the client.

---

Often the decision is best made depending on how dynamic and real-time your content must be vs how performant the application needs to be.

For example, Stackoverflow most likely uses a server-side rendering approach. There are far two many questions for it to rebuild static versions of every question page each time a new post is submitted. The data also needs to be very real-time with users being able to see posts submitted only seconds ago.

However, a blog site, or promo site, which hardly has any content changes, would benefit much more from a static site setup. The response time would be much greater and the server costs would be much lower.

Comment: So if I am to understand this correctly, Gatsby would require building of the entire stackoverflow site, including every question, which would then have to be sent to the client when it hits the stackoverflow homepage? Would this not be possibly gigabytes of data being downloaded just to view the site?

Comment: @Sean Only the built version of the homepage would be sent to the client, however the server would need to store built versions of every question as static HTML files. I keep Gatsby gives the benefit of both static and SPA in that if you were then to load a question page from the homepage it would carry out an XHR request.

Comment: Do you really mean that the HTML is **parsed**? That seems wrong. I would have set the HTML is "generated".

Comment: *"it does mean that any changes to data require a full rebuild over the application server side."* That's not true in general. If I create a new blog post for example, I just need to generate the page for the new post and update the index page.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point RE parsed/generated. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling Regarding page generation, in theory you're correct, however typically a full rebuild is processed as a new blog post may need to appear on lists such as "recent posts","similar posts". If builds are required that often that this could instead be batched overnight for example, then server-rendering may be a better option.

Comment: I think it's important to note that Gatsby handles dynamic content quite well, as long you're happy for that to be fetched dynamically at runtime in the browser. There's no difference between what you can do with a Gatsby app and an ordinary React app in terms of dynamic behaviour, but Gatsby comes with an advanced static build system bolted on top. With Gatsby sites is important to make as much content as possible static, so that its fast, but not so much so that it makes the static part unmanageably large (i.e. every SO question/answer)